# Remove the invoice section from Prestashop 1.6 (addresses.tpl file?)

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to remove the customer invoice address section in my Prestashop 1.6 cart summary page in the customer checkout (see image).

I have a tip that i 'need to comment out/remove the box from **addresses.tpl** file? in the theme folder. Also that i need to know html, to avoid breaking stuff'.

Ive been busy reading html and php books but have not found what i have to do. I just don't know enough to know what specifically to comment or add or maybe its altogether the wrong file to edit.

Can anyone help please?

Here's the code from my addresses.tpl file:

```
{capture name=path}
    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='My account'}">{l s='My account'}</a>
    <span class="navigation-pipe">{$navigationPipe}</span>
    <span class="navigation_page">{l s='My addresses'}</span>
{/capture}

<h1 class="page-heading">{l s='My addresses'}</h1>

<p>{l s='Please configure your default billing and delivery addresses when placing an order. You may also add additional addresses, which can be useful for sending gifts or receiving an order at your office.'}</p>

{if isset($multipleAddresses) && $multipleAddresses}
    <div class="addresses">
        <p><strong class="dark">{l s='Your addresses are listed below.'}</strong></p>
        <p class="p-indent">{l s='Be sure to update your personal information if it has changed.'}</p>
        {assign var="adrs_style" value=$addresses_style}
        <div class="bloc_adresses row">
            {foreach from=$multipleAddresses item=address name=myLoop}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 address">
                    <ul class="{if $smarty.foreach.myLoop.last}last_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.myLoop.first}first_item{/if}{if $smarty.foreach.myLoop.index % 2} alternate_item{else} item{/if} box">
                        <li>
                            <h3 class="page-subheading">{$address.object.alias}</h3>
                        </li>
                        {foreach from=$address.ordered name=adr_loop item=pattern}
                            {assign var=addressKey value=" "|explode:$pattern}
                            <li>
                                {foreach from=$addressKey item=key name="word_loop"}
                                    <span {if isset($addresses_style[$key])} class="{$addresses_style[$key]}"{/if}>
                                        {$address.formated[$key|replace:',':'']|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                                    </span>
                                {/foreach}
                            </li>
                        {/foreach}
                        <li class="address_update">
                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{$link->getPageLink('address', true, null, "id_address={$address.object.id|intval}")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Update'}">
                                <span>
                                    {l s='Update'}
                                    <i class="fa fa-refresh right"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{$link->getPageLink('address', true, null, "id_address={$address.object.id|intval}&delete")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" onclick="return confirm('{l s='Are you sure?' js=1}');" title="{l s='Delete'}">
                                <span>
                                    {l s='Delete'}
                                    <i class="fa fa-times right"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {if $smarty.foreach.myLoop.index % 2 && !$smarty.foreach.myLoop.last} 
                </div>
                <div class="bloc_adresses row">
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    </div>
{else}
    <p class="alert alert-warning">{l s='No addresses are available.'}&nbsp;
        <a href="{$link->getPageLink('address', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Add a new address'}">{l s='Add a new address'}</a>
    </p>
{/if}

<div class="clearfix main-page-indent">
    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('address', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Add an address'}" class="btn btn-default btn-md icon-right">
        <span>
            {l s='Add a new address'}
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<ul class="footer_links clearfix">
    <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm icon-left" href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Back to your account'}">
            <span>
                 {l s='Back to your account'}
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm icon-left" href="{$base_dir}" title="{l s='Home'}">
            <span>
                {l s='Home'}
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, that tpl is for the 3rd step. For the first step, you need to change shopping-cart.tpl in the theme folder also.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have already modified the shopping-cart.tpl file using this guide - https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/128541-how-to-remove-invoice-address/.

i just dont know what to comment out in the addresses.tpl file ( if this is the correct file at all?

Answer (score 0):

The correct file you are looking for is in folder "themes/default-bootstrap" called "shopping-cart.tpl".

And a good solution for you would be this at line 516:

```
            {foreach from=$formattedAddresses key=k item=address}
            {if $k eq 'invoice'}
            {else}
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"{if $k == 'delivery' && !$have_non_virtual_products} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                    <ul class="address {if $address@last}last_item{elseif $address@first}first_item{/if} {if $address@index % 2}alternate_item{else}item{/if} box">
                        <li>
                            <h3 class="page-subheading">
                                {if $k eq 'invoice'}
                                    {l s='Invoice address'}
                                {elseif $k eq 'delivery' && $delivery->id}
                                    {l s='Delivery address'}
                                {/if}
                                {if isset($address.object.alias)}
                                    <span class="address_alias">({$address.object.alias})</span>
                                {/if}
                            </h3>
                        </li>
                        {foreach $address.ordered as $pattern}
                            {assign var=addressKey value=" "|explode:$pattern}
                            {assign var=addedli value=false}
                            {foreach from=$addressKey item=key name=foo}
                            {$key_str = $key|regex_replace:AddressFormat::_CLEANING_REGEX_:""}
                                {if isset($address.formated[$key_str]) && !empty($address.formated[$key_str])}
                                    {if (!$addedli)}
                                        {$addedli = true}
                                        <li><span class="{if isset($addresses_style[$key_str])}{$addresses_style[$key_str]}{/if}">
                                    {/if}
                                    {$address.formated[$key_str]|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                                {/if}
                                {if ($smarty.foreach.foo.last && $addedli)}
                                    </span></li>
                                {/if}
                            {/foreach}
                        {/foreach}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
```

Comment: Do i need to add this whole section of code at 516?

Comment: Yeah can replace everything between the foreach loop that starts at line 516. I only added 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (or maybe rather hack) to removing the invoice box from the cart summary was to add some code to the blockpermanentlinks.css file.

```
#block-order-detail .col-xs-12.col-sm-6 .address.item.box,
.order_delivery .col-xs-12.col-sm-6 .address.alternate_item{display:none}
.col-xs-12.col-sm-6 #address_invoice,
.checkbox.addressesAreEquals{visibility:hidden}
```